# GitHub - корректная работа с ветками

Tags: git, github, heroku, git-commit, git-branch

Всем привет. Делаю бота для телеграма. Код деплою на Heroku. На гитхабе у меня есть 2 ветки: dev и master. Ветка dev используется для разработки, с нее настроен автоматический деплой на Heroku. В эту ветку может осуществляться множество коммитов. В конечном итоге, когда, к примеру, сделал какую-либо рабочую фичу, я хочу обновлять код в ветке мастер. Пробовал делать merge ветки dev c master, но когда пушу в ветку master, естественно, пушатся все коммиты, которые делал до этого в ветку dev. Хотелось бы, чтобы в итоге в master я мог запушить обновленный код, но одним коммитом, соответственно, одним комментарием (добавлена фича такая-то), чтобы не было этого множества коммитов, которые я делаю в ветку dev. Извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый, с гитом пока не особо силен, заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вам нужен git squash

Comment: Получилось, спасибо! Если вдруг кто еще будет искать, делал по данному мануалу https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/27-how-to-squash-commits-and-why-it-is-needed